# for loop value side by side jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a for loop where a get values. I want to make the values side by side like for example

```
value 1 , value 2 , value 3
```

when I do my for lopp I get

```
value 1,
value 2,
value 3
```

my for loop is like this

```
    <span id="spanid"></span>
    for(var i = 0 ; i < data.lenth; i++){
        console.log(data[i].value)
        $('#spanid').text(data[i].value);
    }

data = [{
    "value": "008-408-601-000",

}, {
    "value": "002-408-641-000",

}, {
    "value": "001-002-003-000",

}]
```

`UPDATE`

How can I put it in span like the format i want it to be

Comment: That is because `console.log()` prints on new line.

Comment: You have to concatenate them first as console.log() write out a new line after

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use an array like this :

```
var data = [{ "value": "008-408-601-000"}, { "value": "002-408-641-000"}, {"value": "001-002-003-000" }];

var valueTab = [];

$.each(data, function( index, obj ) {
  valueTab.push(obj.value);
});

console.log(valueTab.join(", "));
$("#spanid").html(valueTab.join(", "));
```

Answer (score 1):

You can append the result in comma separated string and then print the result:

```
var result= "";
for(var i = 0 ; i < data.length; i++){
  result=+ i==0 ? data[i].value: "," + data[i].value;
}
console.log(result)
```

Answer (score 0):

You got ech value on new line because each `console.log()` prints on  a new line.

You can use `.map()` with `.get()`

```
var arr = $(data).map(function(){
    return this.value
}).get().join(' , ');
$('#spanid').text(arr);
```

Comment: is there no way that i work it with for loop because i need to set up other values as well so i need it to be in that for loop

Comment: You can setup other values in this loop too.